# Images 404-Not Found

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, product-images, store-view, apache2

I just installed a fresh copy of Magento 1.9.2.3. Now my issue is when I try to upload any image, be it product, category, transactional email, ect. it gives me the little broken image placeholder. Now the steps I have tried so far:

Changed \media folder to 777
Flushed all Cache (Magento and images)
Read endless questions on similar issues but to no avail.
This is happening in the frontend and Admin
I have checked the link it creates to the image and when I put that in the address bar it gives me a "404 not found" error.
I have checked that the image is indeed uploaded to the folder that the site is pointing to.  If I upload an image directly to the server via FTP i.e. my logo it works fine.  but nothing uploaded by Admin works.
Note: I have had Magento running on this server previously, but it is one to two versions older.

URL is http://southernperformanceparts.com - In case you want to take a look

Can anyone give me some direction here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

***TL;DR:***

You need to check the differences between the VERSIONS in use on the working vs. broken sites AND ONLY then check the two `.htaccess`files to see what might be different.  There are backwards-incompatible changes affecting the the way Magento interacts with apache's mod_rewrite module and the configuration directives the three files that could have something to do with what's going on.

But there's no point in spending any time worrying about any of that if your "working" sites on that host are running an older version vs. the "broken" one.  Figure that out, and you'll know if you need to do a lot of troubleshooting or just re-work your theme customizations to work with the specifics of 1.9.2.3

*** END TOO LONG DON'T READ SUMMARY***

Ok, so now that's out of the way, I'm going to remove all the other potential troubleshooting steps until we get the above confirmed.  No point in filling this up with theoretical stuff just yet,

Comment: The only problem with that, is that I have other Magento installations on this same server and same account in fact, and they are working fine.  It seems though that sense I have installed the latest version of Magento its not working on this particular installation.

Comment: Tommy are you running those other installations as part of a multi-site network?  If so, you may be correct - there would only be one single Apache confit file for the whole multi-site network and you can probably ignore this suggestion.  If you're running those other installations with their own complete installation as separate Magento installations and you're using Apache on a shared hosting environment, then I am pretty confident that you will have a master httpd.conf that is governing every website on that server & EACH of those web sites running Magento will have a separate config file.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, I am running in a shared enviroment, that is run by a hosting company.  I have a reseller account.  Now the magento installation are separate installations, each in sub accounts under my main reseller account.  It just seems to be having this problem on this one particular installation, which so happens to be the latest version of magento.  The other instances are a version or so behind, if that makes any difference.

Comment: So that detail that should help you immensely (see my updated answer above for the full explanation, :  You have two things at play here that may be a primary root cause of the problem and one question I can't be sure about.

Comment: I am completely lost.  But I was looking through my .htaccess file and some stuff referencing image upload are commented out.  Below is what is in that .htaccess on the root of my magento installation.

Comment: Not sure how to post my .htaccess file

Comment: 1st, can you confirm the version of Magento running on the other sites vs. the fresh 1.9.2.3 ?  There are differences in that file's default config between 1.9.2.1, 1.9.2.2, 1.9.2.3 due to [security patches](http://www.maximehuran.fr/en/magento-hacker-alert-guruincsite-infection/) and updates to [the base installers to incorporate those patches](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.2.html) into the latest builds.  It's possible if it was modified by either you, a vendor plugin or a patch or was changed in the installer it won't work vs. the old sites.

Comment: yes it is version 1.9.2.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34992/discussion-between-bryan-bj-hoffpauir-and-tommy).

Answer (score 1):

Just on into magento/media folder where you can find .htaccess file rename it .htaccess_bck clean the cache and see if it iss working or not.

Comment: I renamed the htaccess file and cleared the cache and that did not help